# CRM 2011 asyncoperationbase delete failing plugins

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I imported 3 million customers to the system through SSIS and apparently one of the plugins is failing and I am unable to fix it as I don't have the code. Now in table `asyncoperationbase` I have 3 million system event for that plugin, system is putting everything on waiting until that execution for the plugin is finished. And its throwing exception on each call so system is taking almost 1 hour for each two thousand records.

Please suggest what I can do to fix this. I tried updating the table and setting the status to completedcanceled for those 3 million records but CRM stopped working so I am restoring the backup I took before executing the update.

Answer (score 1):

if you are restoring the backup taken prior to the import, you can just disable the plugin before running the import.
If it's important that the plugin runs during the import, you'll have to contact who wrote it to get the source code, or use a decompiler to get it yourself.

Comment: The backup I restored was after the import , anyway I updated AsyncOperationBase table but now I made the right update I guess , I changed all of the statuses to completed,failed while stopping CRM totally and it went fine , but I believe Microsoft shall have a solution for such case , Database update is not support and such case can cause to stop system for days.